# In ControlValueAccessor writeValue() is not called when calling registeredOnChange()

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
@Component({
  selector: 'image-handler',
  templateUrl: 'image-handler.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ImageHandlerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class ImageHandlerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor{
  @Input() customFormEntity: ImageHandlerEntity;
  value: string;
  setValue(value: string) {
    console.log(`setValue() ${value}`)
    this.onChange(value);
  }
  onChange = (_value: string) => {
    console.log('onChange() not overridden')
  };
  onTouched = () => {
    console.log('onTouched() not overridden')
  };
  writeValue(value: string): void {
    console.log('writeValue is called ', value)
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: (value: string) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

1. I am calling `setValue(value+"0")` when a button is clicked, which triggers `onChange()` but `writeValue` is not called.
2. My `formControl` has a default value of `name`, this default value triggers `writeValue` first time.
3. When I check value in `formControl` by accesing `formGroup.controls.name.value` , it is changed to new value set.

Comment: I guess you are confusing the data flows - writeValue function is a way to communicate changes in your component to the outer world. On the other hand onChanges is way to communicate changes from outer worlds to your component. In your setValue method you should call writeValue, not onChange. In short writeValue should be called by your code from your component when you want to notify about changes outer world.

Comment: Ya its confusing, but i saw many article which don't https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83 which just leave write value as i did, can you link any example.

Comment: Hm, it seems that i am confusing the data flows :)

Comment: I do not think that you call onChange it should call writeValue - by calling onChange you notified angular that data changed but there is no reason for angular to notify you back with the same value by calling writeValue.

Comment: your comment make sense to me

Comment: I just got the error 'TypeError: dir.valueAccessor.writeValue is not a function`